# Difference among the sentences

Tags: difference

What is the difference among the following sentence or are they same?

> What I **most detest** is smoking.
>
> What I **the most detest** is smoking.
>
> What I **detest the most** is smoking.
>
> What I **detest most** is smoking.

Thanks in advance.......

Comment: Please read through [this meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1001/please-use-specific-titles-dont-just-ask-is-this-grammatically-correct) and then edit your question to give it an improved title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form

> What I the most detest is smoking.

is wrong. Or at least soemthing no native speaker would say. Any of the others is acceptable, and there is no large difference in meaning.